# Can Leptospirosis be spread through human urine

Tags: human-biology, pathology

I am wondering if Leptospirosis can be spread via the urine of an infected human individual. All of the sources I have been able to find on the web have stated that the disease is primarily spread through infected animal urine, however, none of them mention human urine.

However, Wikipedia states:

> After 7 to 10 days the microorganism can be found in fresh urine

Which would imply that it could be spread via the urine of an infected individual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be spread from human to human through urine but it is very rare seeing as we are relatively clean creatures (most of the time) and our excrement hardly ever comes into contact with other individuals without first being purified.

Sources:

- [Leptospirosis](http://www.cfsph.iastate.edu/Factsheets/pdfs/leptospirosis.pdf)
- [CDC: Leptospirosis infection](http://www.cdc.gov/leptospirosis/infection/)